# Labview DLL Import

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport, labview

I've created a dummy project (C++) "to create DLL" and
for a C_Wrapper written:
Myclass.h

```
#pragma once
//#include <QString>
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass(double, double);
~MyClass();
double Add(double,double );
double Subst(double, double);
double Mult(double, double);
double Divid(double, double);
bool Vergleich(double,double);
long Avg_num(float *, long, float *);
unsigned int NumInteger(char * inputString);
//QString GibEinString(double, double);
private:
double m_a, m_b;
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"


MyClass::MyClass(double a,double b)
{
 this->m_a = a;
 this->m_b = b;
}

MyClass::~MyClass(){ }

double MyClass::Add(double a, double b) 
{
  return a+=b;
}
double MyClass::Mult(double a, double b)
{
  return a*=b;
}
double MyClass::Subst(double a, double b)
{
  return b-=a;
}
double MyClass::Divid(double a, double b)
{
  return (b / a);
}
bool MyClass::Vergleich(double a,double b)
{
   if(a>=b) return true;
   else return false;
}

long MyClass::Avg_num(float *a, long size, float *avg)
{
 float sum = 0;
 if(a != NULL)
 {
    for(int i=0;i < size; i++)
    sum = sum + a[i];
 }
  else
    return (1);
   *avg = sum / size;
    return (0);
   }
    unsigned int MyClass::NumInteger(char * inputString)
   {
     int lastDigit = 0;
      int numberOfNumbers = 0;
      int stringSize;

       stringSize = strlen(inputString);
     for(int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++)
      {
      if (!lastDigit && isdigit(inputString[i]))
        numberOfNumbers++;
        lastDigit = isdigit(inputString[i]);
       }
       return numberOfNumbers;

    }
```

C_Wrapper.h

```
#pragma once
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { 
#endif

typedef struct Wrapper
{
  void *MYClass;
}Wrapper;

DLLIMPORT Wrapper createWrapper(double a, double b);
DLLIMPORT void destoryWrapper(Wrapper LV_ref);

DLLIMPORT double Add(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b);
DLLIMPORT double Subst(Wrapper LV_ref ,double a, double b);
DLLIMPORT double Mult(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b);
DLLIMPORT double Divid(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b);
DLLIMPORT bool Vergleich(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b);
DLLIMPORT long Avg_num(Wrapper LV_ref,float *a, long size, float * avg);
DLLIMPORT unsigned int NumInteger(Wrapper LV_ref, char * inputString);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
 #endif
```

C_Wrapper.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "C_DllWrapper.h"


DLLIMPORT Wrapper createWrapper(double a, double b)
{
  Wrapper wrapper = {static_cast<void*>(new MyClass(a,b))};
  return wrapper;
 }

 DLLIMPORT void destoryWrapper(Wrapper LV_ref)
 {
   MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
   delete myClass;
  }
  DLLIMPORT double Add(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b)
  {
   MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
   return myClass->Add(a, b);
   }

   DLLIMPORT double Mult(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b)
   {
     MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
     return myClass->Mult(a, b);
    }

    DLLIMPORT double Subst(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b)
    {
      MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
      return myClass->Subst(a, b);
     }

     DLLIMPORT double Divid(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b)
     {
       MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
       return myClass->Divid(a, b);
      }
      DLLIMPORT bool Vergleich(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b)
      {
        MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
        return myClass->Vergleich(a,b);
       }
       DLLIMPORT long Avg_num(Wrapper LV_ref,float *a, long size, float * avg)
       {
         MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
          return myClass->Avg_num(a,size,avg);

          }
         DLLIMPORT unsigned int NumInteger(Wrapper LV_ref, char * inputString)
          {
            MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref.MYClass);
             return myClass->NumInteger(inputString);
            }
```

when I import the DLL in Labview, does almost everything.
My question refers to a function for mainly:

```
DLLIMPORT Wrapper createWrapper(double a, double b)
{
 Wrapper wrapper = {static_cast<void*>(new MyClass(a,b)) };
 return wrapper;
}
```

how can I initialize in Labview?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do it with a struct containing the pointer, instead use directly the pointer in the wrapper function, and use the ptr type in LabVIEW

It becomes

```
typedef void* Wrapper;

DLLIMPORT double Mult(Wrapper LV_ref, double a, double b)
{
  MyClass *myClass = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(LV_ref);
  return myClass->Mult(a, b);
}

DLLIMPORT Wrapper createWrapper(double a, double b)
{
  Wrapper wrapper = reinterpret_cast<void*>(new MyClass(a,b));
  return wrapper;
}
```

Comment: This is in fact the exact typedef used in extcode.h by the name InstanceDataPtr, which is used for arbitrary data types in the callback functions for example. Personally, I'd advocate to use the intptr_t/uintptr_t types, which are generated by the CLFN wizard when selecting the corresponding types under numeric. Also note that the reason for using these types are so that the code is portable across LabVIEW bitness (32/64bit).

Answer (score 0):

Header File

```
#pragma once
#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif

 extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void* createWrapper(double a, double b);
 extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void destoryWrapper(void *instance);
 extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) double Add(void *instance, double a, double b);
```

......

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#endif
```

Source File:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "C_DllWrapper.h"


 extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void* createWrapper(double a, double b)
 {
   return new MyClass(a, b);
 }

 extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) void destoryWrapper(void *instance)
 {
   MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
     delete myClass;
 }
 extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) double Add(void *instance, double a, double b)
 {
   MyClass *myClass = static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
   return myClass->Add(a, b);
 }
```

....
so is Okay !!